# Возможна ли такая формулировка

Tags: грамотная-речь

Если будешь часто использовать полотенце, оно "запреет". В каких случаях вы могли бы использовать слово "преть", приведите, пожалуйста, ряд таких случаев, и объясните, почему.

Comment: https://поискслов.рф/wd/%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%B5%D1%82%D1%8C

Comment: http://search1.ruscorpora.ru/search.xml?env=alpha&mycorp=&mysent=&mysize=&mysentsize=&mydocsize=&dpp=&spp=&spd=&text=lexform&mode=main&sort=gr_tagging&lang=ru&nodia=1&req=%EF%F0%E5%F2%FC

Answer (score 2):

Лучше использовать следующие выражения:

Если будешь часто использовать полотенце, ***оно будет преть***.

Если будешь часто использовать полотенце, ***оно станет прелым***.

Хотя в словаре есть глагольные формы с приставками, но на многих стоит пометка **разг**., кроме того, у них **малая частотность** употребления, так что их можно отнести к устаревающим.

**ПРЕТЬ,** ; нсв. 1. (**св. *сопреть***). Тлеть, гнить от сырости и тепла. Сено преет. 2. Разг. Мокнуть и воспаляться (при некоторых поражениях кожи). Место ожога ***прело***. Под гипсом рука преет. 3. (св. ***взопреть***). Разг. Сильно потеть. П. в шубе. П. на солнце. П. над задачкой (мучиться, долго и упорно занимаясь чем-л.). 4. (св. ***упреть***). Разг. Вариться, поспевать на медленном огне (о пище). В чугунке преет каша.

**ЗАПРЕТЬ,** -преет; запревший; св. **Разг. Начать преть; стать прелым.** Сено запрело. <Запревать, - нсв.

**Примеры:**

Прошлое лето выдалось дождливое, и, когда метали сырое сено, присолили его, чтоб **не сопрело.** [Виктор Астафьев. Последний поклон (1968-1991)]

Пошли дожди, **запрела** листва, наступил самый печальный месяц ― ноябрь. [М. М. Пришвин. Анчар (1925)]

Сено в них от долгого употребления **запрело** и обратилось в твердую пыль. [О. С. Минор. Это было давно... (1933)]